# How do I create a custom camera layout for Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

I am working on an android app that will require the camera. I know that I can use the built in camera app to take photos. However, I would like to have a more custom look (probably another UI and some extras).

Can someone of you guys give me a general approach on how to achieve that? That would be awesome, thank!

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/28/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-for-your-camera-in-android/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice tutorial to accomplish it.

[Camera Integration with Surface View](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-android-camera-to-take.html)

You can make your custom changes on the `SurfaceView` according to your requirements.

Comment: Hey we are now in 2019 and I wonder if there was any proper way to do it now or if this is still the best way to customize camera ?